# Displaying an image to a JApplet?

Tags: java, swing, japplet

I had a question about how to display a simple image to a JApplet. For some reason nothing shows up when I run this code:

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;


public class Main extends JApplet{

Image backgroundFile;
public void init(){
    setSize(1500,750);
    backgroundFile = getImage(getCodeBase(), "Background.jpg");
}
public void paint(Graphics g){
    g.drawImage(backgroundFile, 20, 20, this);
}
}
```

It's not as if the code throws an error or something (that would be much more preferable!), rather nothing appears on the screen.

Comment: Are you 100% sure that you're looking in the right place for the image? Myself, I usually use `ImageIO.read(...)` to get my images

Comment: It's probably not in the right place. I use this way too, but make sure that images are in the binary folder. Or print where getCodeBase() is and make sure your image is in there (for me it's the bin folder).

Comment: @JakeByman: You can [make that your answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17463/163188).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks guys! That was exactly it. I feel so stupid, it just wasn't in the bin folder, rather the main project directory! :P Silly mistake, but thanks again!